# Unity WebGL onclick game fIrst it goes fullscreen issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, web, unity-webgl

1. Build And Run my project.
2. Run my game with chrome browser.
3. When i click my game it goes Full Screen.
4. I want to solve 'first click it goes full screen issue'.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stop the Unity WebGL fullscreen default action for my Unity 2019.1.3 project by editing the UnityLoader.js file found in the "Build" directory created when you make a build.

**I removed** "(e.requestFullScreen||e.mozRequestFullScreen||e.msRequestFullscreen||e.webkitRequestFullScreen)&&(a.indexOf("Safari")==-1||s>=10.1)?1:0" from the "hasFullscreen:function()".

**B E F O R E :**

hasFullscreen:function(){var e=document.createElement("canvas");return(e.requestFullScreen||e.mozRequestFullScreen||e.msRequestFullscreen||e.webkitRequestFullScreen)&&(a.indexOf("Safari")==-1||s>=10.1)?1:0}

**A F T E R :**

hasFullscreen:function(){var e=document.createElement("canvas");return}

I have not thoroughly tested this yet on all browsers, but so far it has stopped the "dreaded FullScreen attack" when viewing my WebGL build in Chrome, firefox, Vivaldi and Safari browsers.

Clearly this is a hack.